# C# - Calling Method 30 times in a second and Creating Screenshots "Bitmaps" - Screen Recorder FPS

Tags: c#, task, screen, recorder

This is what I have done and I can get about 20 FPS but I cant increase it to 30 Frames Per second, it begins to lag and memory increases. I dont even know if this is suitable for making screen recording. I am new to C#. I want to make simple screen recorder that can record at least 29 - 30 FPS Stable. I saw the other examples on making screen recorders but they are not recording in 30 FPS. I wan to be able to adjust the FPS. What is the best way to do it? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenRecorder1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Recording Size
        Size CaptureSize = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

         // Capture Thread 1
        Thread captureThread1;      
  
        int count_FPS = 0;
  
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }

         //FPS:::::::::::::::::::::START:::::::

        //Timer FPS - Display
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer FPS_TimerSec;
        
        // FPS - Timer Settings
        private void FPS_TimerSec_Settings()
        {
            FPS_TimerSec = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            FPS_TimerSec.Interval = 1000;
            FPS_TimerSec.Tick += new EventHandler(FPS_TimerSec_Tick);
            FPS_TimerSec.Enabled = true;
            FPS_TimerSec.Start();
            
        }

         // FPS -Timer - Tick
        void FPS_TimerSec_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              
            current_fps_label.Text = count_FPS.ToString(); // Display FPS
            count_FPS = 0;
           
        }

        //FPS:::::::::::::::::::::END:::::::

        // Load
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Timer
            FPS_TimerSec_Settings();

            // Capture - Thread
            captureThread1 = new Thread(Record12);
            captureThread1.IsBackground = true;
            captureThread1.Start();
        }

        // Aborts the Thread On Form Close // Stops Crashing on Form CLose
        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if(captureThread1.IsAlive)
            {
                captureThread1.Abort();
            }

            base.OnClosing(e);
        }

           public  void Record12()
           {
              while(true)
              {
                Task.Delay(40).Wait();
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    count_FPS++;
                    CaptureImage();
                });
              }
           }
    
        private  void CaptureImage()
        {
            using( Bitmap b = new Bitmap(CaptureSize.Width, CaptureSize.Height))
            { 
                  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                  {
                      g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, CaptureSize, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                 
                  }

                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImage != null)
                    {
                        Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                    }

                    Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImage = b.Clone(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

                    Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

                      //Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImage = b;

                  }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWIV8.png)

It runs ok on 20FPS but If I lower the sleep time to 10 "Task.Delay(10).Wait();". The whole OS is slow now and FPS are not Increased.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/125I0.png)

Comment: Could you take a little time and format the code?

Comment: You mix Thread & Task: Bad Idea. Then you try to _display_ the captured image! This is e x p e n s i v e. Drop that. Then you may be able to increase FPS.

Comment: `captureThread1.Abort();` << NO NO ! Forget that this method exists. Use a bool to end the loop or whatever suits you but have the thread die gracefully.

Comment: How much memory do you have?  Use Task Manager to see if you are using all you memory (when you reach the memory limit the code will slow down due to memory being swapped onto disk); and to check if you have any memory leaks.

Comment: Hi, I had memory leaks but now it seams to be stable at 113MB but when I press and hold the left mouse button on the Window close button the memory increases. I dont press the close button but only hold the Left mouse button and move the mouse away and do it again and it increases the memory. I will try to format the code, remove the .Abort(); and I will write again. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: If I remove the code for showng the recording in the picturebox the fps are not increased.

Comment: I found this I will try to understand how they did it https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX.